# Can I work more than 40 hours for second employer on German Blue card in 2024

Tags: germany, blue-card, working

I am on blue card in Germany working for any employer and he is allowing me to work for second employer as well for upto 40 hours. So is it legal to work for second employer in Germany being a blue card holder?

Comment: Up to 40 hours per *what*? A week? A month? A Year? And how long do you work for your first employer during that time? Some answers would be illegal, regardless of residence permit, even for Germans.